# Changes in Flutter Riverpod 2.0

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod, flutter-riverpod

Recently, Flutter Riverpod 2.0 was released. I'm not sure what has changed with Flutter Riverpod 2.0. I hope someone can explain these changes to me.

If anyone can tell me what the changes are, I'd really appreciate it. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Check out the [change log.](https://pub.dev/packages/riverpod/changelog#200) Also check out this article on [riverpod 2.](https://codewithandrea.com/articles/flutter-state-management-riverpod/?utm_source=Newsletter&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=flutter-state-management-riverpod)

Comment: @VrajShah Can you answer this question and summarize what exactly has changed?

Comment: It all depends on which version of riverpod you were using before?

Comment: @Ruble I was using the `2.0.0-dev.7` version of `flutter_riverpod`. The latest is version `2.0.2` of `flutter_riverpod`, which is Flutter Riverpod 2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you used to pass parameter `ref.read`, now you should pass parameter `ref` => removed typedef Reader (as I understand, related to complication of testing), for example:

```dart
final myClassProvider1 = Provider<MyClass>((ref) {
  return MyClass(ref);
});

// or using tear-off

final myClassProvider2 = Provider<MyClass>(MyClass.new);

class MyClass {
  MyClass(this.ref);

  [-] final Reader reader;
  [+] final Ref ref;
}
```

For a quick solution, you can create your own `Reader`. However, this is not recommended, BUT will work as a quick fix.

```dart
typedef Reader = T Function<T>(ProviderBase<T> provider);
```

2. In the meantime, you can use `overrideWithProvider` instead `overrideWithValue`.

And check with [riverpod/changelog](https://pub.dev/packages/riverpod/changelog). Also, you can wait for the official article from Remi Rousselet:

> An article is in progress and will be linked here once available.